# Periodic background sync in PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am new to periodic background sync, What I want to achieve is that my website should ping to the server at 5 hours of interval by doing so It will receive data from server which will then be processed. I wanted to know if it's possible to set minInterval in periodic background sync to 5 hours or we can't. If their is another method to achieve this can you please give me some source or even an code example might be good.

In this following example of MDN they have set it to one day. Can I reduce it to 5 hours.?

```
async function registerPeriodicNewsCheck() {
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  try {
    await registration.periodicSync.register('get-latest-news', {
      minInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });
  } catch {
    console.log('Periodic Sync could not be registered!');
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you just adjust the minInterval to `5 * 60 * 60 * 1000`?